# Selenium throws weird error on changing to new tab

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a weird error throwing up while switching tab using selenium web driver.
here is the code that throws the error

```
        var tabs = WebDriver.WindowHandles;
        WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[tabs.Count - 1]);
```

This code just switch to a newly open tab. but it fails when with this

```
invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string

(Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11- 
14T08:25:53'

System info: host: 'DESKTOP-9QCDGLU', ip: '10.194.143.155', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'

Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

The passed value .Window() is a string but the error tells that the argument is invalid.

Comment: Is it `WebDriver.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length-1])`?

Answer (score -1):

As long as you are using the same window that webdriver opened you shouldn't need to switch. You may try to switch to the window again after the redirect.

Save you window handle:

```
String myWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

redirect to the page you want and then call switchTo using the window handle:

```
driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle );
```

Does your page contain any frames? It may also be possible that you are not in the correct frame after the redirect.

Comment: But the same code works. there is just one machine which the code does not work

Comment: In your code (original poster), you define it as var.  What language is this?

Comment: @EduCielo you may be missing some libraries. remember the same library you use for windows wont work in mac